# Can I influence the merge strategy used by "recursive" when applying a git stash?

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-stash

I have a set of debug utilities living in a git stash slot; I'm moving between branches which differ only very slightly regarding the changes in the stash. I `git stash apply` the top stash on the respective branch to test a feature.

However I ran into a proper merge conflict in one of the branches, but I want to prefer what's in the stash, so I want the merge-strategy "recursive" to prefer the version coming from the stash (I *guess* that'd be "theirs", cf. `man git-merge` section `MERGE-STRATEGIES`, subsection `recursive`).

Can I somehow tell `git stash apply` what merge strategy to use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can just do the merge yourself.  The stash commit's named `stash`.

```
git cherry-pick -n -m1 -Xtheirs stash
```

Cherrypick does a merge with the cherrypick's parent as the base. [Stash commits record the worktree state with two parents, the checked-out commit and the stashed index](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#_discussion).

The `-m1` tells cherrypick to use the first parent as the merge base, when as here there's any ambiguity about exactly which changes you want merged.  The `-n` says not to commit the result.

This will produce a worktree and index with changes that match the ones in the stashed worktree. If instead you want to apply the changes in the stashed index, cherrypick `stash^2` instead; alternately, if you want to apply the changes from the stashed index (i.e. the added aka staged aka indexed content) to the stashed worktree use `-m2` rather than `-m1`.

If you want to merge *only* to the worktree, do

```
savetree=`git write-tree`
git cherry-pick -n -m1 -Xtheirs stash
git read-tree $savetree
```

That's enough to handle the case in the question here (applying a handy set of changes), but it doesn't completely reproduce everything stash does for you.  Applying the stashed index changes only to the current index and the stashed worktree changes only to the current worktree is just plain finicky.  `git stash` is a script in `/usr/libexec/git-core/git-stash` if anybody wants to see it.

Answer (score 3):

No, not without modifying the `stash` script (you'll find it in the `git-core` directory).

Instead of doing that I'd use `git stash branch newbranch [stash-id]` to turn the stash into a real branch.  This will:

- check out the commit the stash was made on
- `git checkout -b newbranch`
- `apply --index` and (on success, which should be always) `drop` the stash.

(You can restore that stash by `git stash save`-ing immediately afterward, if you want to keep it around as a stash, and then `git stash apply --index` to put it back into effect on the new branch.)

At this point, you can commit the index and/or commit the new working directory, and/or fuss with it on the new branch, all as needed/desired, and then you have a "real branch" you can merge.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem and ended up using a convoluted process with a temporary branch. IMO, this could be easily fixed if the stash command passed -X parameters through to the merge command. Consider this an ugly workaround.

Net effect: apply the stash to the current master, discarding any differences in favor of those in the stash.

1. Create a temporary branch for the stash, as suggested by @torek.

   ```
   git stash branch tmp [stash-id]
   ```
2. Check in your changes. Use any message, as this commit will not be permanent.

   ```
   git add --all .
   git commit -m 'tmp commit'
   ```
3. Rebase the `tmp` branch onto your destination, using the 'ours' merge strategy

   ```
   git rebase -X ours master
   ```
4. Reset the temporary commit, adding changes to your current index

   ```
   git reset HEAD^
   ```
5. Clean up the temporary branch

   ```
   git checkout master
   git branch -d tmp
   ```

This can be quite convenient when both the stash and master contain some identical changes (e.g. if a collaborator and you both rename a file).

Comment: Note that this does not preserve the difference between staged and unstaged changes like stash does. They all end up unstaged.