# how to specify default merge strategy on git stash pop

Tags: git

How can I specify default merge strategy when I do a `git stash pop`?

I tried

```
git stash pop --theirs
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is now possible:

```
git cherry-pick -n -m1 -Xtheirs stash
```

The literal string `stash` now represents the top stash entry (you can also do `stash@{1}` for the one below that, and so on.

More details on how this works are on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314287/can-i-influence-the-merge-strategy-used-by-recursive-when-applying-a-git-stash/19328859).

Answer (score 8):

Side note: you do not want `--theirs`—that's an option to `git checkout`, not to merges—and there is no `-s theirs` *strategy*, there is only a `-X theirs` strategy *option* (I like to call these "extended options" to distinguish them from `-s` strategies).

The answer, however, is that you can't: it is simply not supported as part of the `git stash` code.

It *is* possible to do it a different way.  [The `git stash` script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-stash.sh), which is a shell script you can copy and modify or run its various bits piecemeal, runs `git merge-recursive $b_tree -- $c_tree $w_tree` to merge in the stashed work-tree commit.  You could do this yourself, manually or by copying and modifying the script, with additional `-X` extended-options.  This is, however, not guaranteed to do [what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43770228/1256452).  It is only going to affect parts that Git thinks are conflicting, in which case it will favor one side or the other: `-X ours` means favor the `$b_tree`-to-`$c_tree` change, instead of the `$b_tree` to `$w_tree` change, and `-X theirs` means favor the `$b_tree` to `$w_tree` change.  You may well want the entire file from `$w_tree` commit, though, or not to take some change(s) that nevertheless don't conflict.

(It would be easier and more straightforward to make your own commit, which you could make on a private branch; you can then extract individual files, and/or do whatever merges you like, from that commit at any time, and not have to worry about particular internal details of the `git stash` script that might change from one Git version to another.  Note that to merge one particular file at a time, you can use [`git merge-file`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-file.html), but it's kind of klunky.)

Comment: This is not especially good news. So instead of remembering it all I'll probably go for painstakingly: create a [temporary] branch instead of the stash -> checkout target to be updated with the [not anymore] stashed changes -> merge branches where the strategy is available.

Comment: @TomaszGandor: for anything beyond simple stash-checkout-unstash, I recommend making commits on temporary branches anyway. It's way too easy to build up a bunch of anonymous stashes otherwise, and when you come back to them later, there's often no clue what you were doing. Maybe some people can remember, but I confuse myself :-)

Comment: see the answer from @matt-montag for a simple, memorable solution

Answer (score 4):

So if you arrived here after a `git stash pop` with conflicts, looking like this:

```
$ git stash pop
Auto-merging foo.json
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in bar.json
```

and you'd rather just discard what you had stashed in `bar.json`, the easiest way is to checkout ours:

```
$ git checkout --ours bar.json
```

The stuff coming out of the stash is considered "theirs." So if you want to discard it, check out "ours."

Comment: This simple solution is great! one clarification: you run it after running pop and seeing the message that 'both modified' a file (in other words, the pop sets you up vs needing to specify strategy as part of the pop command). As you might expect, `git checkout --theirs bar.json` also works if you want to keep the stashed version instead.